# Getting R functions to operate on a single row

Tags: r, function, row

I'm not really sure how to phrase my question but what I'd like to do use the max function to choose the max value from a couple of different columns.  But I'd like it to be done  by each row.  I'd like to think that since I can add columns across the rows as such that max would work the same way but no such luck, it picks the max value for those columns across the entire frame.  What am I misunderstanding here?   And is there a solution that doesn't involve looping through the frame and sub-setting out a row at a time?

```
example <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9))
colnames(example) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")

example$thisworks <- example$col1 + example$col2 + example$col3
example$thisdoesnot <- max(example$col1,example$col2,example$col3)
```

Comment: `apply(X = example, MARGIN = 1, FUN = max)`

Comment: hi Paul, in the "thisworks" column, the values are 12,15,18 which are rowsums but you are talking about max values. Which do you want rowsums or the max from each row?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your usage in your example

```
max(example$col1,example$col2,example$col3)
#> 9
```

You are looking for `pmax`

```
pmax(example$col1,example$col2,example$col3)
#> 7 8 9
```